# Edit table data using auto mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Hi i am building a web application for school. 
I am trying to update student information, i already did teacher part

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(Teacher teacher)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var data = teacher;

            return View("TeacherForm", data);
        }

        if (teacher.Id == 0)
            _context.Teachers.Add(teacher);
        else
        {
            var dataInDb = _context.Teachers.Single(c => c.Id == teacher.Id);

            dataInDb.Name = teacher.Name;
            dataInDb.Designation = teacher.Designation;
            dataInDb.EducationalQualification = teacher.EducationalQualification;
            dataInDb.DateOfBirth = teacher.DateOfBirth;
            dataInDb.PhoneNumber = teacher.PhoneNumber;
            dataInDb.StartDate = teacher.StartDate;
            dataInDb.EndDate = teacher.EndDate;
            dataInDb.Status = teacher.Status;
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Teacher");
    }
```

But in Student part i want to use auto mapper for map data

```
if (student.Id == 0)
            _context.Students.Add(student);
        else
        {
            var dataInDb = _context.Students.Single(c => c.Id == student.Id);

            Mapper.Map(student, dataInDb);
        }
```

but its not working. I try to edit data but the table data remain same.
its relay difficult to write every property for student.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Define "not working"

Comment: there is no error. and the table data remain same.

Comment: You appear to be missing a call to _context.Update(student).

If adding that call doesn't fix your problem, can you set a breakpoint after the mapping is completed and verify that the mapping did succeed?